# Access GPU as PCI device

Tags: linux-kernel, gpu, nvidia

I am new to the GPU OS kernelspace world.
I would like to access GPU memory as a PCI device through its memory exposed on the BAR using for exmaple `dev_alloc ()` which is allocating memory and returns an address to this address.

```
void *addr;
addr = dev_alloc ()
//check that the allocated address is in the device bar range 
if(In_bar_range(virt_to_phy(addr))) {
WRITE_ONCE(addr[0], 0);
READ_ONCE(addr[0]);
}
```

I also tried mapping using pci_iomap as follows

```
  void* __iomap map;
  u32 val;
  map=pci_iomap(pci_dev,0,8);
  iowrite8(0, map);
  val=ioread8(map);
  dev_info(&dev " value = %ud ", val);
```

Trying to read from the values fails. It does not return 0. It returns a garbage value. I do not know whether there is a problem in addressing translation (IO_MMU) or if I am missing some kind of synchronization between the CPU and the GPU or if it is another problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you already have to work with, and it might vary based on the kernel version, but I'm assuming you already have a pointer to the device.

If you don't already have one, you will first need to obtain an iomem mapping through [`pci_iomap()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.5/source/include/asm-generic/pci_iomap.h#L13) (`asm/pci_iomap.h`) passing a pointer to the device (`struct pci_dev`) and the PCI BAR number. Then, as explained in [`DMA-API-HOWTO`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) you should be able to read/write through this mapping using one of the `io{read,write}*()` functions [defined in `asm/iomap.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.5/source/include/asm-generic/iomap.h#L50).

Comment: I am already allocation memory on the GPU, get the allocated virtual address  
check that this address is within the range of address  exposed by BAR (virtual address to phy) but when I write to this address then read from it I got different values than what I wrote seems garbage value or I am missing somekind of synchronization

Comment: @HazemAbaza well, then you should post a different question (or edit this one) which includes a [mre], otherwise it's hard to help you out.

Comment: I added minimal code

Comment: @HazemAbaza ok, that is a little bit better, but still not enough. Did you read my answer? Did you try using `pci_iomap` and `ioread/iowrite`? Also, what's `in_bar_range`? It doesn't seem to be defined by Linux.

Comment: yes, I tried them as added to the question, still return is not correct

Comment: @HazemAbaza Hmm, then there must be some other problem. You should try adding the code of a minimal complete module that reproduces the issue, otherwise it's hard to tell.